# getting scale value to list index by pressing a button

Tags: python, button, tkinter, scale

I'm beginner with Python and have code below. I would like to set the scale value to list index by pressing a button and then print the list item, tried two days but can't make it. I do understand why it always takes the first index, this is because the scale value is always 0 when I run the code but I don't understand why it remains 0 even I change the value of the scale and press the button. Can someone help me? Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def on_click():
    label.config(text = list[index])

slider = Scale(root, from_=0, to=5, resolution=1, orient=HORIZONTAL)
slider.pack()

list = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05']
index = slider.get()

label = Label(root)
label.pack()

button = Button(command=on_click)
button.pack()

#print(list[index])

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. Within a function, even if it's operating on a global variable, it can't change anything about that variable other than within the function if you don't declare it global within that function (and it's bad practice to do declare it global inside the function).

Comment: Add the `index = slider.get()` to the top of the function.

Comment: This works with a small modification, thank you very much!